# Wordpress: Can I use get_post_meta in my Plugin?

Tags: wordpress

So I'm trying to reference custom field values in a plugin I'm building.  All I need to do at this stage is grab the values and store them in variables.  This is my code to get the custom field value of pageName:

```
<?php
     global $wp_query;
     $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
     $pageName = get_post_meta($postid, 'pageName', true);
     wp_reset_query()
?>
```

So when I try to echo that out, I get nothing.  I notice that my plugin runs before the head or anything else, so it's the first code in the source.  My hunch is that this is due to timing and the value just isn't there yet.  Is there a way to make my plugin, or this chunk of code, wait until the custom field values are there before trying to grab them?

I'm trying to avoid doing anything in the theme files so this can be a stand alone plugin that I can share.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the solution!  I wrapped the whole thing in a function to put it in the footer, which made sure that everything it needed was there.

```
//----This function is wrapped around the code for my plugin

function dataLayerInject() {
*ALL MY CODE*
}

//----This drops my code into the footer

add_action('wp_footer', 'dataLayerInject');
```

Comment: I think you're making some bad assumptions and using even more bad code for that you're trying to do. Nikhil's answer above is much better than this.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can get the value of any post meta of the custom post type.

Just make sure that you are receiving the correct post_id in the `$postid` variable.
If you get the correct id of the post type you can get any meta field

Example:

```
global $post;
if ($post->ID) {
    $media_id_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'media_id', true);
}
```